# How to add date time picker in unlayer drag and drop editor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, editor

I'm trying to add a date picker to my custom tool below, I have added it and it also renders on the editor however when I click on any date it is not being rendered/not getting selected. I looked up unlayer docs but couldn't find anything.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
unlayer.registerTool( {
    name: 'Footer',
    label: 'Footer',
    icon: 'fa-calendar',
    supportedDisplayModes: ['web', 'email'],
    options: {
      default: {
        title: null,
      },
      text: {
        title: 'Footer Options',
        position: 1,
        options: {
          
          text: {
            label: 'Text',
            defaultValue: 'ENTER Footer Here',
            widget: 'text', // built_in property editor
          },
          
          backgroundColor: { // Property: backgroundColor
            "label": "Background Color", // Label for Property
            "defaultValue": "none",
            "widget": "color_picker" // Property Editor Widget: color_picker
          },
          dateTime:{
            "label": "Date Time", // Label for Property
            "defaultValue": "",
            "widget": "datetime" // Property Editor Widget: color_picker
          }
        },
      },
    },
    values: {},
    renderer: {
      Viewer: unlayer.createViewer({
        render(values) {
          return `<div  style="font-size:${values.font}; color: ${values.textColor}; text-align:${values.textAlign}; background-color:${values.backgroundColor}" >${values.text} ${values.text.dateTime}</div>`;
        },
      }),
      
      head: {
        css: function (values) {},
        js: function (values) {},
      },
    },
    
  })
```